# Blocked by Content Security Policy when visiting icloud.com with firefox

Tags: firefox

does anybody know why I'm getting the following issue when visiting icloud.com with firefox. I've tried disabling all add-ons and protection, but still it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just found out it's the following setting that's preventing icloud.com from loading:
After all it's caused by an add-on. I thought I already tested with all add-ons disabled, perhaps I didn't. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you disable this protection per site by clicking on the 3 vertical dots and unchecking "Spoof `Referer` header" instead of globally as your answer suggests. A great thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

[image: click the uMatrix toolbar icon, then the 3 vertical dots and uncheck "Spoof Referer header"]